# How to make shared_ptr thread safe in this case?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, shared-ptr

In boost doc([Shared_ptr doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety)), I see there is a example which is thread unsafe:

```
//--- Example 4 ---

// thread A
p3 = p2; // reads p2, writes p3

// thread B
// p2 goes out of scope: undefined, the destructor is considered a "write access"
```

How to deal with this case? how can I control if p2 has go out of scope?

Comment: It would be more helpful if we knew what *you* were trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same rule applies to (almost) all types: don't access them in one thread if they are being destroyed in another thread.

And the same solution is applicable: use mutexes or atomic operations to synchronise concurrent access to variables that are shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 try `atomic_store`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_store/

Example:

```
atomic_store(&p3, p2);
```

More examples:

```
// thread A
p3 = atomic_load(&p2);
...

// thread B
atomic_store(&p2, make_shared<Foo>());
```

Comment: This is only thread-safe if all access to `p3` are also done using the relevant atomic functions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely this is true. Thank you for the point. I've decided that solution with mutexes are obvious.